# Bootstrap Multiple Popover - Loading Content via Ajax TypeError

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have several popovers (on a tags) that make ajax calls to populate their data-content. I'm using the following code to make the call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.withajaxpopover').bind('hover',function(){
        var el=$(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: el.attr("data-url"),
            data: el.attr("alt"),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                el.attr("data-content", data);
            }
        });

        console.log(el.attr("data-content"));
        el.popover('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

and then making calls like this:

```
<a href="#" id="test1" title="blabla" class="withajaxpopover" data-url="/ajax/project">blabla</a><br><br>  
<a href="#" id="test2" title="test2" class="withajaxpopover" data-url="/ajax/ports/">hahahaha</a>
```

When I hover over one link, the popover comes up correctly, however after one popover has displayed, I get the following error when I hover on any other popovers:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'popover'
```

When I look at the console, for all subsequent hovers the ajax is returning the correct data, but the popover just isn't appearing. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g6eRB/ but i'm not sure, can you try and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to use a whole other extension to accomplish what I needed. See: http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard has much better ajax support and hover capabilities then bootstrap popover. And the js is very easy to modify to accommodate any specific needs. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.withajaxpopover').bind('hover',function(){
        var el=$(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: el.attr("data-url"),
            data: el.attr("alt"),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                el.attr("data-content", data);
                el.popover('show'); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```